# I was given someone else's visa, stamped in my passport

Tags: visas, uk, passport-stamps

I applied for a UK visa but I received it with the wrong stamp. Somebody else's visa is stamped in my Passport. What do should I do?

Comment: Your passport was returned by courier? There should have been a letter included with it, that explains what to do if there is an error in the visa.

Answer (score 70):

This is a serious error that will have to be corrected by the consulate. You should contact the VFS office where you applied immediately and explain they've put someone else's visa in your passport.

Comment: You might like to add a reference to [this page](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/correcting-an-incorrect-endorsement-ecb19/correcting-an-incorrect-endorsement-ecb19) "If an applicant finds, before they’ve arrived in the UK, that their visa has been issued with an incorrect endorsement they must contact their visa application centre immediately to correct it." I would guess this also applies if the correct endorsement but for the wrong person has been stamped.